# 'sudo' in terminal always rejects my password

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sudo

I need to use sudo for some things, but I always get:

```
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I do not know why, the password is certainly correct, and whenever I am prompted to login as admin by other pieces of software with a GUI, everything works fine. It's only in the terminal that my pw is always rejected. Do I maybe somehow have to tell the system what the username of my admin account is, or anything like this?

Comment: Can you switch to root with `su`?

Comment: no, it just tells me "Sorry"

Comment: Password of which user you are typing? Does it have any strange characters?

Comment: I presume you realise you must type your own password, rather than root's password...

Comment: I have tried every password of every user on the computer now, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
read a;echo $a
```

Need to check that password is actually written as typed.

Answer (score 0):

Root might not have the right permission to connect to database based on that hostname or password .
Try this instead with user :

```
mysql -h your_host_name -p
```

Then put your password.